# How can I remove duplicate objects in an order_by query?

Tags: django, django-models

```
>>> a = group.objects.order_by('groupname')
>>> print a
[<group: beginner 593785332>, <group: beginner 903647323>, <group: blbrz 229225098>]
```

I don't want to have objects with similar `goupname`, I want to have distinct `groupname` for each object:

```
[<group: beginner 593785332>,  <group: blbrz 229225098>]
```

What can I do?

```
from django.db import models
class accounts(models.Model):
    twitterid = models.IntegerField()
    credit    = models.IntegerField()
    activate  = models.TextField()
    ban       = models.TextField(blank=True)
    others    = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.twitterid)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['twitterid']

class group(models.Model):
    groupname        =  models.TextField()
    accounts=models.ForeignKey(accounts)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.groupname, self.accounts)
```

Comment: Could you show us your `models.py` with the `group` model?

Comment: Sounds like you're actually seeking accounts, and the name of their group? Sorted, first by group, then twitter name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database backend were PostgreSQL, you could do it with a queryset:

```
a = group.objects.order_by('groupname').distinct('groupname')
```

Unfortunately you are using SQLite, so you would preferably do it in python :

```
a = group.objects.order_by('groupname')
groupnames = set()
b = []
for item in a:
  if a.groupname not in groupnames:
    b.append(a)
    groupnames.add(a.groupname)
a = b
```

Comment: NotImplementedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: What if you try `a = group.objects.distinct('groupname').order_by('groupname')`?

Comment: not working becuse DISTINCT is not supporting SQlite im using sqlite .

Comment: What is your database backend? It's in your settings file.

Comment: 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'

Comment: sqlite doesn't support distinct field names